# In asp.net core controller, why does ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow() throw "AsyncFlowControl object must be used on the thread where it was created."

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, threadcontext

I am attempting to suppress the flow of the execution context across asynchronous threads. I've written below code, but it throws an error -

```
InvalidOperationException: AsyncFlowControl object must be used on the thread where it was created.
System.Threading.AsyncFlowControl.Undo()
Web1.Controllers.ValuesController+<Get>d__0.MoveNext() in ValuesController.cs
+
                throw;
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
```

The error is *not* thrown when I debug through the code. It only occurs when I dont debug.

Sample code:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    try
    {
        using (ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow())
        {
            await Switch.Instance.SwitchOn();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var x = ex.Message;
        throw;
    }
    return Ok("Done!");
}
```

Am I going about it the wrong way?

Comment: When the continuation that was set up using `await` is executed, it may be on a different thread than the thread your code was on before `await`.

Comment: Personal opinion; Unfortunately it sounds like a very broken design of `AsyncFlowControl`, given that it uses the word `Async` as part of its name and does not handle this kind of thing, it sounds like it is more thread-based than it is async (which are two different things).

Comment: Seems reasonable to me.  Once you've resumed on another thread, it's too late to suppress flow of execution context.

Answer (score 4):

> I am attempting to suppress the flow of the execution context across asynchronous threads.

Just have to ask: Why?

> I've written below code, but it throws an error

This errors happens when you restore execution context flow on a different thread that you suspended it on.

To fix this error, just don't use `await` within the `using` block:

```
Task task;
using (ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow())
  task = Switch.Instance.SwitchOn();
await task;
```

By keeping the code in the `using` synchronous, you are ensuring you stay on the same thread.